# The same model is not equal

Tags: java, android, junit, junit4, junit5

I was covering my app with JUnitTest to test my room and as documentation

```
@Test
    public void writeCompanyAndReadInList() throws Exception {
        // Insert the company
        Company company = TestUtil.createCompany("MobOS2018");
        mCompanyDao.insertCompany(company);

        // Get the company
        LiveData<List<Company>> byName = mCompanyDao.getCompanies("MobOS2018 AND id =1");

        // Check if the two objects are equals
        assertEquals("Should be equal", byName.getValue().get(0), company);
    }
```

My test:

```
@Test
    public void writeUserAndReadInList() throws Exception {
    HistoryModel historyModel = TestUtil.createHistory(0,"21","3123",22-3-5L);
    mHistoryDao.save(historyModel);
    List<HistoryModel> byName = mHistoryDao.getAll();

    Log.e("-----------i", byName.get(0).getId()+" - "+historyModel.getId());
    Log.e("-----------d", byName.get(0).getDistance()+" - "+historyModel.getDistance());
    Log.e("-----------t", byName.get(0).getTime()+" - "+historyModel.getTime());
    Log.e("-----------c", byName.get(0).getCurrentTimeDate()+" - "+historyModel.getCurrentTimeDate());
    Log.e("-----------c", byName.get(0)+" - "+historyModel);
    Log.e("-----------eq", byName.get(0).toString().trim().equals(historyModel.toString().trim())+"");

    assertEquals(byName.get(0), historyModel);
```

and the log is:

```
E/-----------i: 0 - 0
E/-----------d: 21 - 21
E/-----------t: 3123 - 3123
E/-----------c: 14 - 14
E/-----------c: com.fitnesstracker.model.HistoryModel@e803247 - com.fitnesstracker.model.HistoryModel@5d13a74
E/-----------eq: false
```

I have logged all the fields of model and they are equal but I keep on receiving error that they are not equal(

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<com.myApp.model.HistoryModel@e3b4c6e>
but was:<com.myApp.model.HistoryModel@b9d3f0f>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to overwrite [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) and [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), by default equals is based on the internal object ID (same reference).

The objects stored and loaded are not the same reference. They are two different object with the same values, but you have not defined with overwriting equals, that this should be treated as equals and not based on the reference check.